# Sign two buildTypes with the same certificate

Tags: certificate, keystore, android-app-signing

I have an app that has 2 product flavors, p1 and p2
and two build types, debug and release

when i run the app p1Release or p2Release in android studio, they are each signed with the release certificate.
But when I run p1Debug it's signed with the debug certificate.
However I want p1Debug to be signed with the release certificate.

I've tried the following:

```
android {

    ...
defaultConfig {
    ...
}
productFlavors {

    p1 {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    p2 {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    p3 {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}




buildTypes {

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    release {
        debuggable false

    }
}
```

Here I expect whenever I build p1Debug from AndroidStudio to have it signed with the release certificate.
But that does not happen.
but when I run p1Release it is signed with the release certificate.

How do I fix it for p1Debug ?

*note when i do : Build -> Generate signed apk -> and select the correct configuration, it does sign it correctly.

But i need it to work when i click the run button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```

if you want the flavor signing config to take over:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    signingConfig null
  }
}
```